# Баг скролла модального окна

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal

Есть вот такая страница с модальным окном ([тут](https://codepen.io/renton/pen/pGNbNe)):

```js
 var openBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.js-modal'),
  modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
  for(i=0;i<openBtn.length;i++) {
   openBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    modal.classList.add('is-active');
    document.body.classList.add('modal-open');
   })
  }
  function modalClose() {
   modal.classList.remove('is-active');
   document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
  }
  window.addEventListener('click', function(close) {
   if(close.target == modal) {
    modalClose();
   }
  })
```

```css
body {
   min-height: 3000px;
  }
  .btn {
   display: block;
   margin: 30px auto;
   background: blue;
   color: #fff;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 6px;
   font-size: 36px;
   text-align: center;
  }
  .btn:focus {
   outline: none;
   box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #900;
  }
  /* start position */
  .modal {
   visibility: hidden;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: flex-start;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   opacity: 0;
   perspective: 700px;
   transition: all .3s;
  }
  .modal-inner {
   position: relative;
   max-width: 600px;
   padding: 15px;
   margin: 30px 10px;
   transform: translateY(200px) rotateX(45deg);
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
   border-radius: 20px;
   transition: inherit;
  }
  /* active position */
  body.modal-open {
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  .modal.is-active {
   visibility: visible;
   z-index: 9999;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,.95);
   opacity: 1;
   overflow-y: auto;
  }
  .modal.is-active .modal-inner {
   transform: translateY(0) rotateX(0);
  }
```

```html
<button class="btn js-modal">Open modal window</button>
 <p>Таким образом рамки и место обучения кадров представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки направлений прогрессивного развития. Разнообразный и богатый опыт новая модель организационной деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации дальнейших направлений развития. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также реализация намеченных плановых заданий способствует подготовки и реализации новых предложений. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.</p>
<button class="btn js-modal" style="margin: 1000px auto;">Open modal window</button>
 <div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-inner">
    <p>Повседневная практика показывает, что дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации форм развития. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке новых предложений. Равным образом реализация намеченных плановых заданий представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки существенных финансовых и административных условий. Равным образом укрепление и развитие структуры обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании дальнейших направлений развития. Не следует, однако забывать, что дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании модели развития.</p>
    <p>Повседневная практика показывает, что дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации форм развития. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке новых предложений. Равным образом реализация намеченных плановых заданий представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки существенных финансовых и административных условий. Равным образом укрепление и развитие структуры обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании дальнейших направлений развития. Не следует, однако забывать, что дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании модели развития.</p>
    <p>Повседневная практика показывает, что дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации форм развития. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке новых предложений. Равным образом реализация намеченных плановых заданий представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки существенных финансовых и административных условий. Равным образом укрепление и развитие структуры обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании дальнейших направлений развития. Не следует, однако забывать, что дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании модели развития.</p>
    <p>Повседневная практика показывает, что дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации форм развития. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке новых предложений. Равным образом реализация намеченных плановых заданий представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки существенных финансовых и административных условий. Равным образом укрепление и развитие структуры обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании дальнейших направлений развития. Не следует, однако забывать, что дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании модели развития.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

И в ней есть странность: при активном модальном окне, и при большой его высоте, не работает скролл **колесом**. То есть скроллбаром - без проблем. При этом, если изменить размер окна (либо девТулз открыть\закрыть) - колесо начинает работать. Опытным путем выяснил, что удалив transition - колесо работает.

Chrome 71.0.3578.98. В других браузерах все ок. В местном сниппете тоже скроллится, кстати.

Не могу сказать, что ночами от этого не сплю, просто хотелось бы понять как это (не)работает. Возможно есть известный баг?

**UPD:** при удалении opacity: 0 у .modal, скролл тоже работает.

Comment: Да, интересный баг. Связано с `transition` именно для `opacity`. Можно opacity заменить на `background` и будет нормально работать https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mvOWOr

Comment: @stepan, да, как вариант, спасибо. Правда анимация обратная анимация ("исчезновение") не работает в таком варианте.

Comment: Еще вариант: юзать вместо "opacity" - "filter: opacity()", но поддержка у него похуже.

Comment: Еще момент. Скролл начинает работать, если удалить второе значение "transform". В моем случае это rotateX(45deg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге изысканий, выяснилось, что проблема решается заменой

```
.modal.is-active .modal-inner {
        transform: translateY(0) rotateX(0);
    }
```

на

```
.modal.is-active .modal-inner {
        transform: none;
    }
```

Comment: Есть много способов решить проблему, это вы и сами знаете. А вот причина проблемы - это интересно!

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko причина - баг браузера, видимо. Что ж тут поделаешь.